# How to rig a spine?

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging, armature, path

Friends, I have been pulling my hair out for two days over this, even though it seems so simple. I just want a string of *nondeforming* objects, that follow a curve, and bend along with the armature. If you observe the below screencap, you can see the spine - an applied array of meshes - and the curve. I want the spine to attatch to the head, midsection, and pelvis. Most importantly, I want that to remain consistent when exporting to Cascadeur and/or Unreal. Any help is greatly appreciated, as ever.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you carefully align the mesh spine, then you can Parent>> Automatic_Weights with your Armature.   It is with a common armature that all meshes will appropriately deform (bend) together.  If you want, edit your question to a blend file that includes some of your meshes along with the Armature and "spine" object using [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/)

Comment: @james_t Thats a good solution, but not quite what I'm looking for. See, that method *distorts* the mesh, which I'd rather avoid. If I gotta remodel it, oh well. Oh, also I did as you suggested. The file's got ten iterations out there anyway.

Comment: Not my area, so just a suggestion, not an answer.. deform an array of planes with your armature, on whose faces the non-deforming vertebrae are _instanced_?

Comment: @RobinBetts Thats a good suggestion. Unfortunately - and correct me if I'm wrong - instances and modifiers need to be made real and/or applied in order to export.

Answer (score 2):

You have sixteen vertebrae, so we need 16 bones, parented in a chain.  Here, I made them by subdividing a single new bone:

[image]

You don't want them deforming, so we will weight them by parenting to the armature with empty groups, then manually assigning all of the vertices of individual vertebrae to vertex groups:

[image]

Now we want them to move in a curve, so let's make a bezier curve.  You want this attached to the pelvis, so we'll set its origin at the location of the pelvis bone and bone parent it to the pelvis bone, then adjust its shape to match our desired spinal shape.  (Note: because of this parenting, it is the pelvis that will control the "tilt" of the entire chain of bones.)  You want it additionally attached to two other bones, so we'll want a total of three controls, and we'll create hooks for the last two controls:

[image]

We'll bone parent those empties to appropriate bones.

Now we can make a spline IK constraint for our vertebrae.  We will put this on the last bone in the chain (vertebra.001 in my pic).  We have 16 bones, so we want a chain length of 16.  We don't want the bones to scale, so we will set Y scale mode to None.  We see that the vertebrae snap into place:

[image]

However, we also see that the vertebrae don't reach the end of the curve we've defined.  We can either say, no scaling, in which case we'll have to be careful not to position our armature in such a way that the length of the spine changes, not unless that's what we want to do, or we can allow scaling even though that's fudging it.  If we want to allow scaling, all we have to do is reset Y scale mode on the spline IK constraint back to "fit curve".

We could do further adjustment, to eye, on positioning the spine by moving/rotating/scaling our bezier curve or the hooks that control its upper portions.  That's fine, it's not going to break anything; the bones and the mesh will adjust with your changes.

Now, we want to use this in any arbitrary game engine.  These do not support curves or constraints of any kind-- no export format of which I am aware does.  So after we make animations, we may need to *bake* those animations to visual keyframes, which writes the constrained transforms to the actual transforms.  In order to do this, we would use a "bake action" operation, with settings like the following:

[image]

However, I believe that some exports will bake animations as part of the export process, using default export settings.  In case they do not, it is good to understand how bone constraints can be written into the *animation data* of formats like .fbx via baking.

Note that there are additional layers of complexity we can add on top of this, to deal with issues like bone roll throughout the chain or maintaining a consistent length (I'm fond of double IK, a spline IK first pass feeding into a regular IK with rotation enabled, copying rotation to "seed" the IK.)  But it's not worth getting into the more complicated stuff until you understand the less complicated stuff.  I almost wrote "the simple stuff" but of course none of this is simple :)

Comment: Just to be precise, it isn't that `bone constraints can be written into formats like .fbx via baking`, it is that you can bake the visual effect of constraints into keyframes, which can then be exported. You do not keep the constraints when exporting.

Comment: @Nathan Wow. This is the best possible answer I could have received. I'll put this to use, mark you.

Comment: @L0Lock So I've noted. but that then begs another question: how do you keep everything in line if you want to animate in Cascadeur or somesuch? Or - god forbid - make a ragdoll.

Comment: I would ask, however, would it not be more expedient to just seperate them all by loose parts, then parent them?

Comment: @CfrantzX You could potentially bone parent them instead of armature deforming them.  But that might have (negative) implications for performance in game engines.  My understanding is that each object with a different transform is a different draw call.  You might want to verify that with people that know UE or whatever, because I don't.  Still, you can see that I essentially separated by loose parts to organize my vertex group assignments.

Comment: @CfrantzX Aside from raw deformation rig, anything more complex is basically non-exportable, as there are no standards and each software has its own way of making mechanical parts of rig. You usually rig in the software you want to animate.

Comment: Thats a pisser, isn't it... Despite you guys' great help, I may have to rethink this entire design.